# site CC license, attribution requirement must be done manually

Tags: discussion, licensing

I cannot see how attribution can be done at all, given that only usernames are posted, short of typing in your real name in the post. you would need some way to get the person's real name to do it right if you are doing something with code.

Also, I have an issue with the site licensing my code that I post. what if I want to put my own license up? for instance, a drop-down selection of OSI licenses would be nice, which a person could read through or it could nav to some links at http://opensource.org/licenses/

the person's real name is currently hidden from sight for security reasons. this applies to:

- stackoverflow.com
- serverfault.com
- superuser.com
- stackexchange.com
- etc

please remove the CC license. I don't like someone else licensing my content.

Comment: Whoa. You cross-posted this to a dozen metas. Not the first time, though, and always with the same response. Nothing to see here, we can move on.

Comment: Why should we change the licence just for you?  If you are not happy with other people licensing your content, then don't post - the Internet is a huge place!

Comment: Previous question on Meta.SO: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266626/problems-with-stack-overflows-creative-commons-license-agreement

Answer (score 12):

If you don't like to license your knowledge to someone else, you shouldn't post here. Period.

According to the site's legal page you license the content you post to be reused. If your screen name is all there is, that is your problem. If you want 'proper' attribution, change your screen name.

Answer (score 8):

> I cannot see how attribution can be done at all, given that only usernames are posted, short of typing in your real name in the post. you would need some way to get the person's real name to do it right if you are doing something with code.

If people care about doing it "right" they'll use their real name in their profile. Providing a link to the post and the original author's profile page is enough to give proper attribution if you use part of their question or answer somewhere else.

If you want to license your code, you should be posting it on a code sharing site (or your own site), not on Stack Exchange sites.  Stack Exchange is for questions and answers. That's the content that's being licensed. If you've written a substantial software library or a full application, publish it somewhere else, then link to it in your answers here and explain *how to use it* to answer the question. That way, your source code is still under whatever license you choose to release it with.